# Android: String format with Double value

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I need to create a String using the Formater to display some double float values.  I'm not clear on how to code it.  Here is what I have:

```
Double dWeightInKg = 100;
Double dWeightInLbs = 220:
String headerText = String.format("%.0f kg / %.0f lbs",Double.toString(dWeightInKg) , Double.toString(dWeightInLbs));
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
100 kg / 220 lbs
```

I get a runtimeexception - badArgumentType(formater) on my String.format line.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

%.0f is the format string for a float, with 0 decimal places.

The values you're passing to String.format are String, String when it needs to be Double, Double.

You do not need to convert the doubles to strings.

```
String headerText = String.format("%.0f kg / %.0f lbs", dWeightInKg, dWeightInLbs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have known better!

Comment: Also, you will see the hint that you should explicitly determine the locale for `String.format()`. Avoiding this hint may lead to bugs in your application. More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale

Answer (score 10):

This should work,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
private String convertToFormat(double value){

    return df.format(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was actually something simple.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Double.ToString() since your formatter is already expecting a number. Try this:

```
String headerText = String.format("%.0f kg / %.0f lbs", dWeightInKg , dWeightInLbs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have slept on it before asking!!